# PostgresOperator in Airflow getting timeout

Tags: postgresql, airflow

I made a function in Postgres that have the following statement:

```
FUNCTION
        SET statement_timeout TO "3600s"
     SELECT * FROM schema.table_name
        END 
FUNCTION
```

In Airflow I use the `PostgresOperator` to execute this function, but I receive the message `[2018-06-01 00:00:01,066] {models.py:1595} ERROR - canceling statement due to statement timeout`.

I saw that [`PostgresOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/_modules/postgres_operator.html) uses the [`postgres_hook`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/hooks/postgres_hook.py), and [`postgres_hook`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/hooks/postgres_hook.py) uses the `psycopg2` as connector.

As I see, I can be a timeout by a cli application instead a timeout from the database.

I would like to know how to solve this thing? Do I need to configure the Psycopg in Airflow or can I use some environmental variables to set the timeout to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass in connection arguments into psycopg2 library through the Airflow `extras` property on connection. At the time of writing the postgres_hook supports the following arguments

`['sslmode', 'sslcert', 'sslkey','sslrootcert', 'sslcrl', 'application_name', 'keepalives_idle']`

In order to pass in the `statement_timeout` argument to the PostgresHook you will need to override the `get_conn` of the PostgresHook to accept your desired argument.

Ex. Class Method Override

```
class NewPostgresHook(PostgresHook):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NewPostgresHook, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_conn(self):
        conn = self.get_connection(self.postgres_conn_id)
        conn_args = dict(
            host=conn.host,
            user=conn.login,
            password=conn.password,
            dbname=self.schema or conn.schema,
            port=conn.port)
        # check for ssl parameters in conn.extra
        for arg_name, arg_val in conn.extra_dejson.items():
            if arg_name in ['sslmode', 'sslcert', 'sslkey',
                            'sslrootcert', 'sslcrl', 'application_name',
                            'keepalives_idle', 'statement_timeout']:
                conn_args[arg_name] = arg_val

        self.conn = psycopg2.connect(**conn_args)
        return self.conn
```

You can then specify this argument on the connection `extras` field in the form of a JSON string.

Ex. JSON String in Connection Extras Field

`{'statement_timeout': '3600s'}`

Comment: Probably to overcome this in Airflow we'll use an environment variable to set the `statement_timeout` globally for Postgres. Thanks for your answer.